# How to catch mouse events in an empty QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am facing this problem in Qt5.6.3 (mingw): how can we catch the click event  in a `QListwidget` that has no items (empty). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a mcve ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) so that every one can understand your question.

Comment: I dont understand, what is Empty ListWidget?